# MySQL Stored Procedure returning more than expected

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am starting to play with stored procedures but am having some problems, I am getting more rows than I expect. I have a table with the following data:

```
----------------------
| user_id | username |
----------------------
|    1    |   fred   |
----------------------
----------------------
|    2    |   andy   |
----------------------
```

And have a procedure as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `VerifyUser`(userId INT, userName CHAR(40))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = userId AND username = userName;
END
```

The problem is I am getting a result no matter what I enter for "userName", I seem to be getting the record for user_id=2:

```
CALL VerifyUser(2, 'dontWork');

----------------------
| user_id | username |
----------------------
|    2    |   andy   |
----------------------
```

I can get it to work if I only have userId but when I add the second parameter I get a result no matter what. WHAT AM I DOING WRONG? I am assuming it has something to do with the string parameter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your column name and your parameter name are the same (case-insensitive). Use a different name for the parameter and you will be fine.

Otherwise the DB thinks you mean

```
username_column = username_column
```

which is always true.

Comment: WOW Thank you so much juergen! I was under the impression that it was case insensitive! This was driving me up the wall ;-)